# Use external USB webcam instead of webcam on ubuntu 20.04 machine

Tags: ubuntu, usb, camera

I am trying to get an external USB webcam to work on my machine. But all applications use the default webcam on the machine and don't show multiple cameras to choose from. Don't give answers like install cheese or gucview. I have tried that. I have tried all answers in the platform.

Comment: This Q lacks info about WHICH apps you actually want to use like Skype, whatever...

Comment: Also, we don't know anything about your OS... fill in the blanks... which desktop environment, etc.